# Run scene generated in CocosStudio?

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js, cocostudio

I'm trying to figure out the cocos2d Javascript environment. I'm using Cocos Studio v2.1 beta to generate a scene. Right now the scene just has a label so I can know if it worked. I publish it to a Cocos Code IDE project created by Cocos Studio. After some searching, it seems you can load any CSB as a Node by using:

```
var imported = ccs.csLoader.createNode("res/MainScene.csb");
```

[Node seems to be the root object for a lot of different things.](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.0alpha0/d3/d82/classcocos2d_1_1_node.html) I'm looking for a way to take this Node and pass it a call to `cc.director.runScene(imported);`

I tried calling `getScene()` but that seemed like a stretch. `imported` shouldn't have a parent that's a Scene, it IS a scene. I have a main.js that looks like this:

```
cc.game.onStart = function(){
    cc.view.adjustViewPort(true);
    cc.view.setDesignResolutionSize(800, 450, cc.ResolutionPolicy.SHOW_ALL);
    cc.view.resizeWithBrowserSize(true);
    //load resources
    cc.LoaderScene.preload(g_resources, function () {
        var imported = ccs.csLoader.createNode("res/MainScene.csb");
        cc.director.runScene(imported);
    }, this);
};
cc.game.run();
```

When I run the game, it crashes as soon as I run it. Here's the console output:

```
Console: listening on  0.0.0.0 : 6050
Console: listening on  0.0.0.0 : 6060
Ready for GLSL
Ready for OpenGL 2.0

{
    gl.version: 2.1.0 - Build 8.15.10.2622
    gl.supports_NPOT: true
    cocos2d.x.version: cocos2d-x 3.3
    cocos2d.x.compiled_with_profiler: false
    cocos2d.x.build_type: DEBUG
    cocos2d.x.compiled_with_gl_state_cache: true
    gl.max_texture_size: 8192
    gl.vendor: Intel
    gl.renderer: Intel(R) HD Graphics
    gl.max_texture_units: 16
    gl.supports_ETC1: false
    gl.supports_S3TC: true
    gl.supports_ATITC: false
    gl.supports_PVRTC: false
    gl.supports_BGRA8888: false
    gl.supports_discard_framebuffer: false
    gl.supports_vertex_array_object: true
}


cocos2d: fullPathForFilename: No file found at script/jsb_debugger.jsc. Possible missing file.
cocos2d: fullPathForFilename: No file found at script/debugger/DevToolsUtils.jsc. Possible missing file.
cocos2d: fullPathForFilename: No file found at script/debugger/core/promise.jsc. Possible missing file.
cocos2d: fullPathForFilename: No file found at script/debugger/transport.jsc. Possible missing file.
cocos2d: fullPathForFilename: No file found at script/debugger/actors/root.jsc. Possible missing file.
cocos2d: fullPathForFilename: No file found at script/debugger/actors/script.jsc. Possible missing file.
cocos2d: fullPathForFilename: No file found at script/debugger/main.jsc. Possible missing file.
cocos2d: fullPathForFilename: No file found at script/jsb_boot.jsc. Possible missing file.
suffix = csb
textureSize = 0
classname = Node
size = 1
classname = Text
callBackName  cannot be found
size = 0
child = 0882F950
```

The files listed as missing seem to be misnamed. Those files all exist except with .js extensions instead of .jsc.

The project did run fine when main.js had `cc.director.runScene(new HelloWorldScene());` so it seems the project is mostly configured correctly.

I must be loading the Scene incorrectly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there any reason why you are going with an old version? 

I sincirely reccomend you to pick up v3.x and look at the official docs and tutorials ;)

Comment: I'm using what appears to be the latest version of everything. You can see in my output that I'm using cocos-2d-x 3.3. It was the latest at the time of posting. Cocos STUDIO still only seems to be at 2.1-beta.

Comment: Whoops, I guess I misread, my bad!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
jsb.fileUtils.addSearchPath("res");
var node = ccs.csLoader.createNode("res/MainScene.csb");
this.addChild(node);
```

I had to add search path for res directory, otherwise it didn't work.

Comment: This is now: var cssResource = css.load("res/node.csb"); this.addChild(cssResource.node)

Comment: this doesn't work for me. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_localZOrder' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

keep default **`main.js`** and add following code into **`app.js`**:

```
var node=ccs.csLoader.createNode("res/cat_queen.csb");
var node_action=ccs.actionTimelineCache.createAction("res/cat_queen.csb");
node.runAction(node_action);
node.attr({scale:1.5,x:size.width/2,y:size.height/3,});
node_action.gotoFrameAndPlay(0,60, true);
this.addChild(node);
```

then copy folder that contain images in folder **`res`** and paste it outside, near **`res`** folder
ok. now, you can debug to see how to animation run.
contact me with skype koibito10101 and I will tell detail, I can't add picture to decrible for you see @@